# Is it possible to "serialize" a span such that a span could be started, and then picked up after reboot?

Tags: python, trace, open-telemetry

I don't actually have any code, it's more of a conceptual "how might someone do this" sort of question.

I have a python application that I am instrumenting with OpenTelemetry, the application basically does some configuration on the machine that only can be completed after a reboot.
I'd like to be able to create a span at the start of the operation, and when the application picks back up after a reboot it is able to continue with the span.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this sort of thing?